# Take note, this is my favorite thing

Tags: riddle, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, metapuzzles

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #30: Metapuzzles](http://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5889/fortnightly-topic-challenge-30-metapuzzles).</sup>

---

**Please note: This puzzle IS a metapuzzle. If someone wants to put the integrity into question, I'll feel free to privately send an answer. I'd also like to note that the answers provided so far are incredibly partial; there is still a final code to solve, not to mention the fact that the minipuzzles haven't been solved to the fullest yet.**

## Step one: Gathering information

**?. degeneratiVe**

> A simple cipher that utilizes the differents.
>   Key: 177 157 149 144 133 128 103 94 75 62 61 47 33 28 24 0

```
IOEQL LAPEA OCVMM CR, FXDO
```

**1. devolvIng**

> Shouting madness
>
> This minipuzzle, from the ground up
>
> How do they work?
>
> Secret/travel
>
> Mating ghosts
>
> To be it or not to be it
>
> Shift two
>
> Common article

The key is the 5th and 6th concatenated.

```
CBRWB NYOQE IARGY RSWXS IXVBX WBEOG AEBCY, ZJIGD LKZJO MBMKY
```

**?. Gross**

> Key: 6, 10, 19, 19, 28, 64, 55, __

```
JIHSIX JXAKI VKENC BNEHK FAR, KIXSA WDKVD XSH, HHEWH P
```

**?. hiddEn**

> I'm in oranges, but neither salami nor sausage.
>
> I’m in your nightly domino rage, and also find mayhem in orderless societies such as vermin or the minority of people who spend their life a lie.
>
> I know you see me everywhere without knowing, so catch me if you can.
>
> In this one, the answer and the first noun smashed together is the key to everything.

```
ECZGF FQOKA FABTS LNTOF GUOSI S, VT
```

**?. misNomers**

> All my life, I’ve been a part of many things. I’ve really got an incredible story to tell.
>
> I started off a young lad. The first thing I partook in was after high school. I went to *college, the first thing I partook in*. Not much to remember there. The next thing I did was *become a game of chains with a mask at the end*. During this time I actually went on a cruise. I found *love (and shovels, long story) over water*, due to a *highly skilled strike* to the hull by a submarine. I ended up at a funeral, mourning *over the captain*.

The key is the answer backwards.

```
WCDRF VSWSQ MSWNU ESBEH VBNLQ MSWSQ MSWEU XVCTI FDXSU KWXN, XZHCL Q
```

## Step two: Applying information

Remember, take notes and break it down!

```
13  35  36  14  22  14  43  23  46  27  42  17  37  47  27  26  54  33  34  34  47  26  16  13  13  15  22  51  58  31  34  11  31  54  31  36  42  46  43  54  42  16
22  34  46  35  31  14  27  18  31  36  12  23  31  16  12  22  33  51  26  12  15  51  26  51  17  35  55  12  34  15  22  42  13  23  33  15  37  51  12  31  26  16
14  43  34  37  13  54  23  18  15  27  12  55  12  43  33  36  18  55  27  13  35  37  37  31  31  13  58  35  35  11  47  33  31  43  33  13  27  42  31  54  11  14
```

> P.S.
>   I understand that many of the ciphers are solvable without finding the key, but I would like to request that one not use any methods to bypass finding the keys. Thank you!

Comment: The capital letters spell out VIGEN(ere). :/

Comment: @Deusovi What an astute observation.

Comment: I may or may not have made this puzzle too easy for the likes of Puzzling SE. Oh well.

Answer (score 8):

### **Partial Answer**

**hiddEn**

> I'**m in or**anges, but neither sala**mi nor** sausage.
>
> I’m in your nightly do**mino r**age, and also find mayhe**m in or**derless societies such as ver**min or** the **minor**ity of people who spend their life a lie. 
>
>  The hidden word is **MINOR** combined with Oranges(first noun) forms - **MINORANGES** using this as a key gives -
>
>  **SUMS OF DIGITS OF BLANK NUMBERS, IN**

**misNomers**

> There are certain words which are used here - like many, incredible and **captain** which are related to word **MAJOR** backwards gives **ROJAM** using this as a key gives -
>
> **FOURTEEN SEVEN NINE SEVEN ELEVEN SEVEN EIGHT TWO POSITION, LITTLE**

So, the final message we have to go ahead is -

> WORD HIDDEN BY SPACE, STAR
>  WORD INSIDE PHRASES DESCRIBED BY ITALICS TWINKLE TWO TIMES
>  REMOVE LETTERS AS YOU GO DOWN, SECOND FROM TOP, D MAJOR
>  SUMS OF DIGITS OF BLANK NUMBERS IN
>  FOURTEEN SEVEN NINE SEVEN ELEVEN SEVEN EIGHT TWO POSITION, LITTLE

Comment: And domino rage?

Answer (score 7):

### Partial Answer

#### Degenerative

> Taking the differences between the numbers and converting to letters says `THEKEYISMANNEDX`. Decoding with key `MANNEDX` gives `WORD HIDDEN BY SPACE, STAR`.

#### Devolving

> Each of the phrases is a clue to a word, starting at ARGUMENT and removing a letter each time:
>
>  ARGUMENT/AUGMENT/MAGNET/AGENT/GNAT/TAG/AT/A
>
>  Decrypting with the passphrase `GNATTAG` gives `WORD INSIDE PHRASES DESCRIBED BY ITALICS, TWINKLE TWO TIMES`.

#### Gross

> The OEIS easily gives this to be the sum of the digits of the nth perfect number. The next one is 73, and decoding with the key `SEVENTYTHREE` gives `REMOVE LETTERS AS YOU GO DOWN, SECOND FROM TOP, D MAJOR`.

Answer (score 7):

## PARTIAL

The final message is: (Thanks, TechIdiot & Deusovi)

> WORD HIDDEN BY SPACE, STAR 
>  WORD INSIDE PHRASES DESCRIBED BY ITALICS TWINKLE TWO TIMES 
>  REMOVE LETTERS AS YOU GO DOWN, SECOND FROM TOP, D MAJOR
>  SUMS OF DIGITS OF BLANK NUMBERS IN
>  FOURTEEN SEVEN NINE SEVEN ELEVEN SEVEN EIGHT TWO POSITION, LITTLE

When rearranged:

> WORD INSIDE PHRASES DESCRIBED BY ITALICS TWINKLE TWO TIMES (twinkle, twinkle)
>  FOURTEEN SEVEN NINE SEVEN ELEVEN SEVEN EIGHT TWO POSITION, LITTLE (little)
>  WORD HIDDEN BY SPACE, STAR (star)
>  SUMS OF DIGITS OF BLANK NUMBERS IN (in)
>  REMOVE LETTERS AS YOU GO DOWN, SECOND FROM TOP, D MAJOR (D Major)

Removing the parts in brackets, this gives the correct order of instructions:

> 1. WORD INSIDE PHRASES DESCRIBED BY ITALICS
>  2. FOURTEEN SEVEN NINE SEVEN ELEVEN EIGHT TWO POSITION
>  3. WORD HIDDEN BY SPACE
>  4. SUMS OF DIGITS OF BLANK NUMBERS
>  5. REMOVE LETTERS AS YOU GO DOWN, SECOND FROM TOP
>
>  The order of the puzzles is: Devolving Misnomers Degenerative Hidden Gross

"Take notes, and break it down" may refer to:

> The notes of Twinkle, twinkle, little star when played in D Major. 
>  The first notes would be **DDAABBA** which looks about the same length as some of the keys used earlier.

Comment: Oh, didn't noticed that. I was thinking of the final note. Turns out, its unused. :-/

Answer (score 2):

Here's another

### Partial answer

#### Step 1

> As Dave H noticed, the order of the puzzles is:
>  1. Devolving
>  2. Misnomers
>  3. Degenerative
>  4. Hidden
>  5. Gross
>
>  After removing the "Twinkle, twinkle, little star in D major" parts, we see that each of the decrypted cyphertexts is a hint to the next puzzle (in the given order). Using these hints, we can find the following hidden words:
>
>  **1. Devolving**
>  The hint from 5. Gross is
>  REMOVE LETTERS AS YOU GO DOWN, SECOND FROM TOP
>  If we take the second word of the solution, we get "AUGMENT".
>
>  **2. Misnomers**
>  The hint from 1. Devolving is
>  WORD INSIDE PHRASES DESCRIBED BY ITALICS
>  The word described by the phrases in italics is "MAJOR", and this is our hidden word.
>
>  **3. Degenerative**
>  The hint is
>  FOURTEEN SEVEN NINE SEVEN ELEVEN SEVEN EIGHT TWO POSITION
>  If we take the characters at positions 14, 7, 9, etc. from the solution "THEKEYISMANNEDX", we get the word "DIMINISH".
>
>  **4. Hidden**
>  The hint is
>  WORD HIDDEN BY SPACE
>  which hints at "MINOR".
>
>  **5. Gross**
>  The hint is
>  SUMS OF DIGITS OF BLANK NUMBERS
>  The word on the blank should be "PERFECT", so this is our final hidden word.
>
>  So we have the hidden words
>  1. AUGMENT
>  2. MAJOR
>  3. DIMINISH
>  4. MINOR
>  5. PERFECT
>  These are all [interval qualities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(music)#Quality). If we combine this with "Twinkle, twinkle, little star in D major", I think we have extracted all information from step 1.

#### Step 2

> Here it can be noted that all numbers have two digits, and the first digit is always an integer between 1 and 5, and the second digit is always between 1 and 8. Using the information from the first part, we can link numbers from 1 to 5 to the different interval qualities, so these numbers probably correspond to intervals. Conversion yields:
>
> ```
>  A3 d5 d6 A4 M2 A4 m3 M3 m6 M7 m2 A7 d7 m7 M7 M6 P4 d3 d4 d4 m7 M6 A6 A3 A3 A5 M2 P1 P8 d1 d4 A1 d1 P4 d1 d6 m2 m6 m3 P4 m2 A6
>  M2 d4 m6 d5 d1 A4 M7 A8 d1 d6 A2 M3 d1 A6 A2 M2 d3 P1 M6 A2 A5 P1 M6 P1 A7 d5 P5 A2 d4 A5 M2 m2 A3 M3 d3 A5 d7 P1 A2 d1 M6 A6
>  A4 m3 d4 d7 A3 P4 M3 A8 A5 M7 A2 P5 A2 m3 d3 d6 A8 P5 M7 A3 d5 d7 d7 d1 d1 A3 P8 d5 d5 A1 m7 d3 d1 m3 d3 A3 M7 m2 d1 P4 A1 A4
> ```
>
> Another thing to note is that "Twinkle, twinkle, little star" in D major has the following notes:
>
> ```
>  D D A A B B A G G F# F# E E D A A G G F# F# E A A G G F# F# E D D A A B B A G G F# F# E E D
> ```
>
> The number of notes equals the number of numbers per line in the cyphertext. If we use each of the intervals to increase the corresponding note in twinkle, twinkle little star, we get the following:
>
> ```
>  Fx  Ab  fb  d#  c#  e#  c   B   eb  e#  G   dx  db  c   g#  f#  c   Bbb Bb  Bb  d   f#  fx  B#  B#  cx  G#  E   d   Db  db  A#  Bb  e   Ab  ebb Ab  d   A   A   F   B#
>  E   Gb  f   eb  Bb  e#  g#  g#  Gb  db  Gx  G#  Eb  B#  B#  B   Bbb G   d#  Gx  B#  A   f#  G   fx  c   c#  Fx  Gb  A#  B   Bb  dx  d#  cb  d#  fb  F#  Gx  Eb  c#  B#
>  G#  F   db  gb  dx  e   c#  g#  d#  e#  Gx  B   Fx  F   cb  fb  g#  d   e#  Ax  Bb  gb  gb  Gb  Gb  Ax  f#  Bb  Ab  D#  g   cb  Bb  d   cb  B#  f#  G   F   A   E#  G#
> ```
>
> Replacing the notes by notes that sound the same to eliminate some sharps and flats gives the following:
>
> ```
>  G   G#  e   d#  c#  f   c   B   d#  f   G   e   c#  c   g#  f#  c   A   A#  A#  d   f#  g   c   c   d   G#  E   d   C#  c#  A#  A#  e   G#  d   G#  d   A   A   F   c
>  E   F#  f   d#  A#  f   g#  g#  F#  c#  A   G#  D#  c   c   B   A   G   d#  A   c   A   f#  G   g   c   c#  G   F#  A#  B   A#  e   d#  B   d#  e   F#  A   D#  c#  c
>  G#  F   c#  f#  e   e   c#  g#  d#  f   A   B   G   F   B   e   g#  d   f   B   A#  f#  f#  F#  F#  B   f#  A#  G#  D#  g   B   A#  d   B   c   f#  G   F   A   F   G#
> ```
>
> We can also decrease each of the notes:
>
> ```
>  'Bbb 'G#   Cx   Eb   A    F    F#   Eb  'B   'G    E#  'Fb  'Fx  'E   'Bb   C    D    E#   Cx   Cx  'F#   C    Cb   Ebb  Ebb 'Bb   E    E   'D    D#   E#   Ab   B#   F#   A#  'B#   F#  'A#   D#  'B    D#  'Fb
>   C   'A#   C#   D#   B#   F   'Bb  'Gb   G#  'Ax   Eb   C    E#  'Fb   Gb   G    E#   G   'A    Eb  'Ab   A    C    G   'Abb 'B#  'B    Db  'A#  'Gb   G    G#   Gb   G    Fx   Cb  'A#   F#   Eb   E#  'G   'Fb
>  'Ab  'B    E#  'B#   Gb   F#   F   'Gb   Cb  'G    Eb  'A    Db  'B    Fx   Cx  'Gb   C   'G    Db  'A#  'B#  'B#   G#   G#   Db  'F#  'A#  'G#   Db  'B    Fx   B#   G#   Fx   Ebb 'Ab   E#   Fx  'B    Eb  'Ab
> ```
>
> After elimination of some sharps and flats:
>
> ```
>  'A   'G#   D    D#   A    F    F#   D#  'B   'G    F   'E   'G   'E   'A#   C    D    F    D    D   'F#   C   'B    D    D   'A#   E    E   'D    D#   F    G#   c    F#   A#   C    F#  'A#   D#  'B    D#  'E
>   C   'A#   C#   D#   c    F   'A#  'F#   G#  'B    D#   C    F   'E    F#   G    F    G   'A    D#  'G#   A    C    G   'G    C   'B    C#  'A#  'F#   G    G#   F#   G    G   'B   'A#   F#   D#   F   'G   'E
>  'G#  'B    F    C    F#   F#   F   'F#  'B   'G    D#  'A    C#  'B    G    D   'F#   C   'G    C#  'A#   C    C    G#   G#   C#  'F#  'A#  'G#   C#  'B    G    c    G#   G    D   'G#   F    G   'B    D#  'G#
> ```
>
> I don't know whether this is the right way to go (I don't think so to be honest), but maybe it gives someone the right idea how to solve this puzzle

Comment: Almost, but each note of TTLS should only output one note as per "take notes and break it down"